# how to fix "TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32" when I try to resize an image in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to setup an images pipeline that builds an images dataset for Tensorflow that crops the images, but I fail at cropping the picture.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/images) but I want to crop the file to a square and not resize it without preserving the aspect ratio.
Here is my code :

```
#
import tensorflow as tf
#

img_raw = tf.io.read_file('./images/4c34476047bcbbfd10b1fd3342605659.jpeg/')

img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_raw, channels=3)

img_final = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
    img_tensor,
    0,
    0,
    200,
    200
)

img_final /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
```

When I use simple image resize as in the tutorial it works:

```
#
import tensorflow as tf
#

img_raw = tf.io.read_file('./images/4c34476047bcbbfd10b1fd3342605659.jpeg/')

img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_raw, channels=3)

img_final = tf.image.resize(img_tensor, [192, 192])

img_final /= 255.0  #
```

Here is the log :

```
    img_final /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 876, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File ".../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 964, in _truediv_python3
    (x_dtype, y_dtype))
TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.uint8 != tf.float32
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tensorflow doesn't do automatic type casting. It seems that the decoded image is a tensor with dtype `tf.uint8`, you have to cast it to `tf.float32` for the division to work as you expect.

Replace

`img_final /= 255.0`

with

`img_final = tf.cast(img_final, tf.float32) / 255.0`

Comment: Thanks Addy ! I tried also ```img_final = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_final, tf.float32)
``` that does the same thing.

Comment: cool, if the answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer, also consider giving thumbs up, thanks.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer. But since I'm a newby, my thumb up is not displayed :(